# Как реализовать модульную систему в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Писать много строк кода в одном файле неудобно вовсе.
Читал про разные системы модулей, но все они не могут работать без каких-либо сторонних библиотек, сервера, сборщика или еще чего-то. Модули ES6 [не поддерживаются](http://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module) в браузерах *пока*.

Если я хочу писать приложение\сайт\страницу\скрипт\etc и разделять код на части, то мне не обойтись без сервера, сторонних библиотек, которым нужны еще библиотеки, сборщика проектов и прочего?

Пробовал *Browserify*, но надо каждый раз запускать сборку, либо использовать gulp\grunt для того же. Неудобно.

*Require.js* сборки не требует, но организация кода мне не нравится:

```
require(['deps/dep1', 'deps/dep2', 'deps/dep3', 'deps/dep4', 'deps/dep5', 'deps/dep6', 'deps/dep7'],
function (     dep1,        dep2,        dep3,        dep4,        dep5,        dep6,        dep7) {
    return function () {
        return dep1 + dep2;
    };
});
```

**Как реализовать модульную систему наиболее эффективным образом, не обременяя себя ненужными библиотеками?**

Comment: Кажется, хорошей идеей будет использовать es6 модули, при разработке использовать браузер, который поддерживает es6 модули, а для продакшена конвертировать es6 модули в один из множества поддерживаемых браузерами форматов.

Comment: @Дмитрий, хорошая идея, спасибо.

Comment: для browserify/gulp/grunt/webpack есть вотчеры которые сами перезапускают сборку и соответственно пересобирают что изменилось а не все подряд

Answer (score 0):

сейчас браузерной поддержки почти нет. Поэтому ES-модули используются в сочетании с системами сборки, такими как `webpack`, `brunch` и другими, при подключённом `Babel.JS`.
Вот **webpack.config.js**

```
// Для использования нужен Node.JS
// Поставьте webpack:
//   npm i -g webpack
// Поставьте babel-loader:
//   npm i babel-loader
// Запустите его в директории с файлами:
//   webpack

module.exports = {
    entry: "./index.js",
    output: {
        filename: "./build.js"
    },

    watch: true, // просмотр включен

    watchOptions: {
        aggregateTimeout: 100 //время тайм аута просмотра изменений
    },
    plugins: [ ],
    devtool: 'source-map',

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                },
            }
        ]
    },
};
```

вот подробнее [Модули](https://learn.javascript.ru/modules)

Comment: У Вас конфиг первого вебпака (например во втором емнип нельзя опускать полное имя загрузчика), а при npm i webpack на данный момент поставится второй. Соответственно если следовать вашему ответу с нуля кажется будет ошибка.

Comment: извеняйте вот конфиг от второго

Comment: если что не понятно распишу подробнее